# Go to Navigation Controller scene from Navigation Controller that is inside a Tab Bar Controller

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5

I've got following hierarchy in my storyboard:

Navigation Controller A -> UIView B (without Nav bar) -> Tab Bar Controller C -> Navigation Controller D -> UITableView E (with Nav bar D and Table bar C)

Now I want to go from UITableView E to UIView B. When I use a push segue, my Tab Bar Controller C and Navigation Controller D is preserved. I don't want that. My full scene has to be replaced with UIView B that doesn't got any Nav or Tab bars.

How do I achieve this with storyboards?

Comment: you may try hiding navigation bar and tab bar in ViewDidLoad.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:
UIView B (viewWillAppear)

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
```

UITableView E (push to UIVIew B)

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

You can disable the tabbar on the storyboard by selecting the combobox "Hides Botton Bar on Push". To hide the navbar, in "Simulated Metrics" (top left of xCode), and select "None" in the "Top Bar"